# C++ linked list implementation segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am currently trying to learn C++ on my own and have been going through some textbooks and trying to do some problems. While learning pointers, I decided to try and implement a linked list on my own. I have written the program, but keep getting an error that says: "segmentation error (core dumped)". I have searched through other similar questions on this website and although there are a lot on the same topic, none have helped me fix my problem. I'm pretty new to programming and pointers, so any help will be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


struct node
{
   int element;
   struct node *next;
}*start;


class pointerlist
{
        public:
                node* CREATE(int num);
                void ADD(int num);
                int FIRST();
                int END();
                int RETRIEVE(int pos);
                int LOCATE(int num);
                int NEXT(int pos);
                int PREVIOUS(int pos);
                void INSERT(int pos, int num);
                void DELETE(int pos);
                void MAKENULL();
                pointerlist()
                {
                        start = NULL;
                }
};

main()
{
        pointerlist pl;
        start = NULL;
        pl.ADD(1);
        cout << "Added 1" << endl;
        for (int j=1; j<=5; j++)
                pl.ADD(j);
        cout << "The pointer implemented list is: " << endl;
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
                cout << pl.END() << "  " ;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
}  

void pointerlist::ADD(int num)
{
        struct node *temp, *s;
        temp = CREATE(num);
        s = start;
        while (s->next != NULL)
                s = s->next;
        temp->next = NULL;
        s->next = temp;
}

node *pointerlist::CREATE(int num)
{
        struct node *temp, *s;
        temp = new(struct node);
        temp->element = num;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return temp;
}

int pointerlist::FIRST ()
{
        int num;
        struct node *s;
        s = start;
        num = s->element;
        return num;
}

int pointerlist::END()
{
        struct node *s;
        s = start;
        int num;
        while (s != NULL);
        {
                num = s->element;
                s = s->next;
        }
        return num;
}

int pointerlist::RETRIEVE(int pos)
{
        int counter = 0;
        struct node *s;
        s = start;
        while (s != NULL)
        {
                counter++;
                if (counter == pos)
                {
                        return s->element;
                }
                s = s->next;
        }
}

int pointerlist::LOCATE(int num)
{
        int pos = 0;
        bool flag = false;
        struct node *s;
        s = start;
        while (s != NULL)
        {
                pos++;
                if (s->element == num)
                {
                        flag == true;
                        return pos;
                }
                s = s->next;
        }
        if (!flag)
                return -1;
}

int pointerlist::NEXT(int pos)
{
        int next;
        int counter = 0;
        struct node *s;
        s = start;
        while (s != NULL)
        {
                counter++;
                if (counter == pos)
                        break;
                s = s->next;
        }
        s = s->next;
        next = s->element;
        return next;

}

int pointerlist::PREVIOUS(int pos)
{
        int previous;
        int counter = 1;
        struct node *s;
        s = start;
        while (s != NULL)
        {
                previous = s->element;
                counter++;
                if (counter = pos)
                        break;
                s = s->next;
        }
        return previous;
}

void pointerlist::INSERT(int pos, int num)
{
        struct node *temp, *s, *ptr;
        temp = CREATE(num);
        int i;
        int counter = 0;
        s = start;
        while (s != NULL)
        {
                s = s->next;
                counter++;
        }
        if (pos == 1)
        {
                if (start = NULL)
                {
                        start = temp;
                        start->next = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                        ptr = start;
                        start = temp;
                        start->next = ptr;
                }
        }
        else if(pos>1 && pos <= counter)
        {
                s = start;
                for (i=1; i<pos; i++)
                {
                        ptr = s;
                        s = s->next;
                }
                ptr->next = temp;
                temp->next = s;
        }
}

void pointerlist::DELETE(int pos)
{
        int counter;
        struct node *s, *ptr;
        s = start;
        if (pos == 1)
        {
                start = s->next;
        }
        else
        {
                while (s != NULL)
                {
                        s = s->next;
                        counter++;
                }
                if (pos >0 && pos <= counter)
                {
                        s = start;
                        for(int i=1; i<pos; i++)
                        {
                                ptr = s;
                                s = s->next;
                        }
                        ptr->next = s->next;
                }
                free(s);
        }
}

void pointerlist::MAKENULL()
{
        free(start);
}
```

The problem occurs in line 39 of my code (inside main where I write pl.ADD(1)). In this line I was trying to start off the list with the vale 1. There maybe be problems with the rest of my code too, but I have not been able to get past this line to check. Please help!

Comment: Pointerlist is null. You need to create a new instance of pointerlist class before you perform ADD operation

Comment: You should get a good C++ book, which explains what pointers are. Now you send your code here for others to debug.

Answer (score 1):

List is empty at the beginning, therefore it will fail on `s-> next` as `s == start ==NULL` :

```
    s = start;
    while (s->next != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I was able to fix the problem by adding a first function which adds the first element to the list. But now I am having trouble with my END function. It appears to not be entering the loop within the function when it is called. I cannot find a reason for this. Would anyone be able to help me figure out why my END function does not work?